# Why wind effect wont affect rigid body simulation in 2.8?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a simple setup.

An active cube and a passive plane with rigid body physics activated.
An empty with wind physics activated and the strengh set to 1000.

When I play the animation, nothing happen except for the cube falling on the plane...

Did I miss something ?

[image]

Comment: it plays fine with blender 2.83. Was it a bug in 2.8x? Which version did you have the problem with?

Answer (score 1):

yeah this is a weird bug. Try this workaround. Add a particle system to the cube and then delete it straight away without running the animation. Now run the animation and the cube is blown around as expected.

Comment: More importantly, did this bug ever get fixed - or reported for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like rigid body world not auto-updating when foce fields created. Try to reduce "All" weight (to 0.99) in "Field weigts" for rigid body world (in "Scene" tab). Then rebake\recalculate your simulation (run an animation). Now you can change weight back to 1.