# Floating rigid bodies not affected by wind (2.92)

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

I'm trying to make some floating rigid objects blow away in the wind. I have applied a rigid body to all of the objects separately, and have a wind force field pointed at them. When I hit play, the objects all fall unaffected by the wind. What's going on here? I've tried the workarounds in [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125145/why-wind-effect-wont-affect-rigid-body-simulation-in-2-8) but they haven't helped either.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change the strength of your force field from 14 to 5000 and you WILL see a difference ;)

Comment: Presumably the Mass of the objects is too high to notice the '14' strength wind... another option therefore would be to significantly decrease the mass (a block of steel would take virtually no notice of a light breeze but a feather would).

Comment: @RichSedman you are right +1

Comment: Took some fiddling to fine tune it from getting blown away in two frames, but it works! Thanks.